# Is it possible to split a single cell into multiple row entries in a Kendo Grid (MVC)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

This is the desired output of the Kendo Grid with nested rows within cell.

[image]

Thus far, I've seen a template hack but it seems fairly cumbersome and not convenient for our use cases. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'd ask this on the Kendo forums but I was unable to obtain our licensing info on short notice as I'm working for a client and don't own it directly

Cheers

Comment: I'm afraid it can't be done as it is not in the [demos](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index).

Comment: Templates are a vital part of Kendo. You can do some pretty cool stuff with them. Not sure I'd call them a hack...

Comment: I agree with Steve. Templates seem like the solution to this problem.